# How to delete an inner element from a nested list in Python?

Tags: python

I have created a list

```
a = [[3, 4], [5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

I want to delete 3 from this list. What is the command for this?

Comment: `list` is a bad name for your object since it shadows a built-in.

Comment: What tutorial are you using?  Where are you reading about lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy, you can try this

```
del a[0][0]
```

Answer (score 11):

lots of possible ways

```
>>> mylist = [[3,4],[5],[6,7,8]]
>>> mylist[0] = [4]
>>> mylist
[[4], [5], [6, 7, 8]]
>>> mylist = [[3,4],[5],[6,7,8]]
>>> del mylist[0][0]
>>> mylist
[[4], [5], [6, 7, 8]]
>>> mylist = [[3,4],[5],[6,7,8]]
>>> mylist[0].remove(3)
>>> mylist
[[4], [5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Take your pick :)

Comment: +1 for teaching the man to fish.  (I also reformatted and made it clear that `del` is a statement, not a function.)

Answer (score 2):

```
a[0].remove(3)
```

(had to add more text so it was long enough)

Answer (score 2):

Using this:

```
del a[0][0]
```

For a better understanding of lists, dictionaries, etc., I suggest you should read [Dive Into Python](http://diveintopython3.ep.io/)
You'll find Chapter 3 very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, you want to delete all 3s from a list of lists:

```
>>> lst = [[3,4],[5],[6,7,8]]
>>> [[i for i in el if i != 3] for el in lst]
[[4], [5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: I upvoted since the answer is useful, but after more than a year of python programming I still don't see the advantage to list comprehensions like this over something with a couple more lines of code that is perhaps a bit less obtuse. ghostdog74's answer is almost instantly recognizable whereas I always have to pause and mentally parse list comprehensions. <shrug>

Comment: @Bryan: how is this *obtuse*? ghostdog74's answer is incorrect, as it only removes a single 3 it's also deeply nested, which ghostdog74 is trying to avoid by flattening the remove and making it even less readable or pythonic.

Comment: I say it's obtuse because unless you have used a lot of list comprehensions, you have to mentally parse through what is happening. All developers can pretty much instantly recognize and understand nested loops much faster than they can parse something like "i for i in el". Maybe I'm just an old dog that can't learn new tricks, but I prefer explict loops over one-line list comprehensions.

Comment: It's hard to say if ghostdog74's answer is incorrect or not. The original problem says "I want to delete 3". Not *all* 3's. One could interpret it as "I want to remove the first element of the first nested list" or "I want to remove the 3 from the first nested list", or a couple other ways. <shrug>

Comment: @Bryan: and ghostdog74's version is doing neither.

Comment: weird. I get the result [[4], [5], [6, 7, 8]] with ghostdog74's version. Whatever. I don't think his is the best solution, but regardless, it doesn't alter the fact I don't see much advantage in list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't know where "3" is,

```
>>> for n,i in enumerate(list):
...   if 3 in i: list[n].remove(3)
...
>>> list
[[4], [5], [6, 7, 8]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you have list in a list and you want to delete first element from first list. So use:

```
del a[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be careful because you are shadowing the built in name "list".
This

```
a_list = [[3,4],[5],[6,7,3, 3, 8]]

def clear_list_from_item(a_list, item):
   try:
       while True: a_list.remove(item)
   except ValueError:
       return a_list

a_list = [clear_list_from_item(x, 3) for x in a_list]
```

This will modify your original list in place.

Answer (score 0):

two easy ways to remove from a list, if you know the element of concern is at position 0:

```
a[0].pop (0)
del a[0][0]
```